# Should I have an updated count as part of user table?

Tags: php, mysql, select, database-design, count

Let's imagine I have a databases with two tables, Users and Posts. The first table contains a row for each user, the second table a row for each post that users have written. If I want to display a post count on the users' profiles, which of these two strategies work the best:

1. Every time a user creates a post I UPDATE the Users table, +1 a field PostCount;
2. When someone visits the profile I simply run a select statement to get a count of post, for example SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM Posts WHERE id_user = 100;

In the first case I have to UPDATE a table very often, which it could be bad as I believe a table gets locked when doing the update; in the second case I have to run a count every time the user visits a profile. Which poison is the less bitter? Is there any other way?

Comment: so as not to disagree with script47 in a separate Answer, I would say #2 in a comment. You are going to have an index on Post.id_user. It is resolved split second. When you have a real problem, it is a good problem to have (a huge subscriber base), then de-normalize the database. In the meantime you can't screw up the counts and act goofy upon them somehow. Now, if you have a page that lists a bunch of users at once like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/topusers), different story. But you better have that count validity **nailed down** tight.

Comment: @Drew please post an answer, if you're in fact correct why shouldn't. Plus then I'd learn something new too.

Comment: well @Script47 I just think my above comment is just comment-worthy :> As I don't know Parrot's overall system. There is nothing inherently evil with a metric in a user table (like the Answer you just deleted). Just gotta be careful, and without much info, it is knee-jerked opinion-based for me to offer an Answer without qualifying it like a lawyer !

Comment: Hi @Drew and Script47, I posted some additional details under the answer below, in case that helps. Thank you for your insights, by the way!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends on how many times you will display PostCount, especially for a huge amount of Users. If you are going to display it for 1000+ users on a page that will be called a lot of times, then the first solution should be the best. But you need to do [transactions](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.transactions.php) to be sure both tables Posts and Users are updated when adding a new post.

Otherwise, the second solution should be enough, but you should use [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) so that you would get both information from Users and Posts table in only one query. Eg:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id , COUNT(*) AS posts_count 
    FROM Posts 
    GROUP BY user_id
) p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = :searched_id
```

(And anyway you should use a Cache system so that you don't have to do the same SQL query for a same page if shown to several users.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Technically, I am only programming the backend. This should be an Instagram-like application. As the app is still in under development I can't say how popular is going to get, but I would like to implement the most robust solution anyway. For example Instagram /users/user-id API returns the number of pictures and followers of a user. Do they calculate that on the go or is that information stored? I know you can't know the answer, but that is the kind of situation I am in. (:

Comment: just don't over-engineer it til you have 10000 users. Don't be all dressed up with no where to go

Comment: @Drew just don't over-$action it til you have $problem could be the story of my life. (: But I like to think ahead, when I can.

Comment: story of my life too, trying to change that. In the early depths of that despair I would create that memcache server Holo is talking about, so I could get my count (the only user) in 0.01 milliseconds versus 0.02 (mysql has its own cache) :>

Comment: The cleanest way should be the second, as long as you use LEFT OUTER JOINs. You will find that scenario will other tables and other models. That's what is used in most frameworks and most ORM.

Comment: if you are looking for performance, I would avoid ORMs. Plus if you don't, you won't find much support on The Stack for complicated joins.

Comment: Except all the others, using Laravel and SQLAlchemy and Hibernate, waiting for hours for help, never getting it, as we pass them by and chuckle to ourselves something like, "wish I could help you" :> Plus there is nothing in the question that even hints at the need for left outer joins. But these are all just my random musings. That said, I would like to learn Laravel, just not for the actual sql part of it

Comment: but, you have touched on some nice things to consider and showed some helpful code so +1vote. nice job